# AS3 Drag always snaps back to original place?

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

making a simple app with a slider that changes a text box value, but whenever i drop the slider, it snaps back to its 0 position. i need it to stay in place. please help!

code:

```
        theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, slide);


        public function slide(e:MouseEvent):void
    {


            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragstop);
            var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,27,550,0);
            theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.startDrag(false, bounds);
            txtboxint = setInterval(changetextbox, 500);

    }
    public function dragstop(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragstop);
        clearInterval(txtboxint);
        trace("what", e.target.x, e.currentTarget, e.target.name) //  returns proper x value, [object Stage], slider
        trace("almost", theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x);// returns proper x value
        theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.stopDrag();
        trace("last", theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x); //returns proper x value
    }
    public function changetextbox():void
    {
        trace(theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x) //returns proper x value
        theroot.settings_but.phone1txt.text = (Math.floor(((theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x) / 550) * 40));
    }
```

Comment: I think it must be somewhere else in the code the problem is occurring. This looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, slide);


     public function slide(e:MouseEvent):void
     {
        theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, slide);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragstop);
        var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,27,550,0);
        theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.startDrag(false, bounds);
 theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,changetextbox);    
     }

     public function dragstop(e:MouseEvent):void
     {
        theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.stopDrag();
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragstop);
        trace("what", e.target.x, e.currentTarget, e.target.name) //  returns proper x value, [object Stage], slider
        trace("almost", theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x);// returns proper x value           
        trace("last", theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x); //returns proper x value                    theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,changetextbox);  
      theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, slide);
     }

     public function changetextbox(e:Event):void
     {
        trace(theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x) //returns proper x value
        theroot.settings_but.phone1txt.text = (Math.floor(((theroot.settings_but.phone1.slider.x) / 550) * 40));
     }
```

Comment: sorry but again, no go, if i release the mouse anywhere but the slider mc, it stays in place, until i click anywhere else on the screen. then it snaps back. very frustrating..

Answer (score 0):

problem was event bubbling over to main MC, which caused the MC with the sliders within to goto frame 0

thanks for all your help!